# MongoDB - Aggregate on nested array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I want to use `$lookup` in the aggregate method.
The collection I want to do this is like this. It is an array. It has nested objects in the array.

Please notice my problem is with the lookup and the way I want to get my data.
The names of the properties are not so important, the important property is "position_id".

```
[
  {
    name : 'projectName1',
    positions : [
      {
        position_id : id1,
        use : true,
        wage : 0,
        default : true
      },
      {
        position_id : id2,
        use : true,
        wage : 0,
        default : true
      }          
    ]
  }      
]
```

When I lookup on the "position_id" like this:

```
$lookup: {
  from: 'positions',
  localField: 'positions.position_id',
  foreignField: '_id',        
  as: 'positions.positionDetails'
}
```

The result is:

```
"positions": {
    "positionDetails": [
        {
            "_id": "63d78e5096109914dc963431",
            "field": "electrical",
            "regularName": "elc",
        },
        {
            "_id": "63d78e5096109914dc963433",
            "field": "mechanic",
            "regularName": "mec",
        }
    ]
}
```

The `positions` array was changed to an object.

But I want to get data like this :

```
"positions": [
    {
        "position_id": "63d78e5096109914dc963431",
        "use": true,
        "default": true,
        "wage": 0,
        "positionDetails" : {
            "field": "electrical",
            "regularName": "elc",
        }
    },
    {
        "position_id": "63d78e5096109914dc963433",
        "use": true,
        "default": false,
        "wage": 0,
        "positionDetails" : {
            "field": "mechanic",
            "regularName": "mec",
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$lookup` - Join with `positions` collection for the document into `positionDetails` field.
2. `$set` - Set `positions` field.

   2.1. `$map` - Iterate each document in `positions` array and return a new array.

   2.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge the current iterate document from the `positions` array with the result from *2.1.1.1*.

   2.1.1.1. `$first` - Get the first matched element from the result *2.1.1.1.1* and assign it to the `positionDetails` field in the new document.

   2.1.1.1.1. `$filter` - Filter the elements from the `positionDetails` array which match the id.
3. `$unset` - Remove `positionDetails` array field.

```
db.doc.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "positions",
      localField: "positions.position_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "positionDetails"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      positions: {
        $map: {
          input: "$positions",
          as: "pos",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$pos",
              {
                "positionDetails": {
                  $first: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$positionDetails",
                      cond: {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$pos.position_id",
                          "$$this._id"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "positionDetails"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rmjDb5Bnm3d)

Comment: Thank you so much @Yong Shun . it works fine. how can I be that much expert in aggregation? I tried many ways before your answer..., I should learn more about these operators that you have used in the code.

Comment: You are mostly welcome. I also still have a long journey to be an expert. More practice and raising questions if any is the best way to improve. =D And do feel free to read StackOverflow questions & answers, there are a lot of experts to assist and give you a learning boost.